# Insert a row to MySQL table with jsp

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp, jdbc, insert

I want to insert rows to mysql database with an jsp code, but I can´t. 
Here is my jsp code without the html form:

```
<%
String login = request.getParameter("login");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
String full_name = request.getParameter("full_name");
String ulevel = request.getParameter("ulevel");
String team_id = request.getParameter("team_id");

Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
int updateQuery = 0;
if(login!=null && password!=null && full_name!=null && ulevel!=null && team_id!=null){
if(login!="" && password!="" && full_name!="" && ulevel!="" && team_id!="") {
    try {
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/android","root","root");
String queryString = "INSERT INTO users(user_id,login,password,full_name,ulevel,team_id) VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
pstatement.setString(2, login);
pstatement.setString(3, password);
pstatement.setString(4, full_name);
pstatement.setString(5, ulevel);
pstatement.setString(6, team_id);
updateQuery = pstatement.executeUpdate();
if (updateQuery != 0) { %>
```

When I press SUBMIT, the webpage shows me this:

> type Status report   message   descriptionThe requested resource () is
>   not available.

**p.s.:** column `user_id` is set to `autoincrement` in mysql table, so I use `null`.

But I dont know, that´s the right way...

I run the code from netbeans 7.0.1

Comment: As a side note: Don't put logic in JSP, move it to a servlet.

Comment: I have another jsp code for selecting columns from table...it works fine without servlet.

Comment: You miss the point, it will work fine but it is considered a bad practice to mix presentation layer (JSP) and business logic layer (Servlet).

Comment: @ftom2 +1. Here is nice explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/814702

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since `ID` is *auto-incremented*, get rid of it from the list, preparedstatement is looking for index `1` on its parameters.

```
String queryString = "INSERT INTO users(login,password,full_name,ulevel,team_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
pstatement.setString(1, login);
pstatement.setString(2, password);
pstatement.setString(3, full_name);
pstatement.setString(4, ulevel);
pstatement.setString(5, team_id);
```

this one below is *not tested*

just start you parameter with `1` because there are only 5 parameters to be defined.

```
String queryString = "INSERT INTO users(user_id,login,password,full_name,ulevel,team_id) VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
pstatement.setString(1, login);
pstatement.setString(2, password);
pstatement.setString(3, full_name);
pstatement.setString(4, ulevel);
pstatement.setString(5, team_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The error was in html form, at attribute `action`, where i had an source file, which i never had before. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
String queryString = "INSERT INTO users(user_id,login,password,full_name,ulevel,team_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

You should not use anything not even `null` for query!